# How to iterate over a list and create a json array from it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How can i iterate over a list and create a Json array to send back from my controller?

Pseudo code is welcome!

Answer (score 4):

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("foo");
    list.Add("bar");

    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and on the client:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("Foo")', function(list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        alert(list[i]);
    }
});
```

And if you want to send an array to your controller action as input:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string[] foos)
{
    ...
}
```

you could do the following:

```
var array = [];
array.push('foo');
array.push('bar');
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("foo")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ foos: array }), 
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
//To create an array of objects
String name = <get name from your list>
object.put(key name, key value);       // example: object.put("name","whatever string you want");

//To create an array of arrays
JSONArray subarray = new JSONArray();
subarray.add(name);

//Put your object or subarray into the main JSONArray
array.add(object);
// OR
array.add(subarray);
}
```

Now send your JSONArray to your webpage from your controller like so:

```
            request.setAttribute("jsonarray",array);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
```

and then using javscript in your webpage,

```
var jsArray  = eval('(' + '<%=request.getAttribute("jsonarray")%>' + ')');
```

You can now iterate through it in javascript:

```
    for(var i=0;i<jsArray.length;i++)
{
  var getName = jsArray[i];
}
```

Hope this helped!